# Why user form submission message is not printing(after stopping confirm form submission alert by browser )

Tags: php, forms

**Query to insert the values in database**

```
$query = "select * from logintb WHERE username = '$username'";
$query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0){
    echo 'username already exists!!';                                                   
}else{
    $query="insert into logintb values('$fullname','$username','$gender','$address','$pnumber','$email','$encrypted_password')";    
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if($query_run){                                 
        echo "Registered successfully!";
        echo("<script>location.href = 'signUp.php';</script>");

    }else{                                              
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error!") </script>';
    }
}
```

basically i was working on how to prevent the browser confirm form submission alert.Because it causes data to enter twice in database.so i redirect the page to itself.right now it solved my problem but couldn't print the message that **user registered successfully** because it reloads the page.any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the insert and check into `if (isset($_POST['submit-user'])) { }` where `submit-user` is your button

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-user'])) {

    $query = "select * from logintb WHERE username = '$username'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0) {

        echo 'username already exists!!';

    } else {

        $query="insert into logintb values('$fullname','$username','$gender','$address','$pnumber','$email','$encrypted_password')";    
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        if ($query_run) {

            echo "Registered successfully!";

        } else {                                          

            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error!") </script>';

        }

    }

}

// HTML <form method="post"></form> goes here...
```

Comment: but this will not prevent the browser from giving confirm form submission alert.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:-

```
echo "<script>alert('Registered successfully!');</script>";
```

The above will show the successful message as an alert and after clicking will reload the page . Or otherwise , go for JavaScript / JQuery registration process to make it faster and without reload .

Comment: my question was why the echo' ' was not printed!

Comment: You had already given the answer why it was not printed and you asked for a solution .